# Changing the color of embeded text

Tags: javascript, web, colors, embedded-resource

I have been trying to get this text color to be white rather than black so it can be more readable on our site. Unfortunately I have been unsuccessful in changing it. Im not sure what I am missing lol im sure its right in front of me though. I did go through a website to embed this as well.

```
<div id="medium-widget">  
</div>
<script src="https://medium-widget.pixelpoint.io/widget.js">

</script>

<script>MediumWidget.Init({renderTo: '#medium-widget', params: {"resource":"https://medium.com/paradigm-fund/c%C3%B8smos-network-proposal-to-add-the-gravity-dex-onto-cosmos-hub-is-live-tendermint-invests-in-c68d8600e35b","postsPerLine":3,"limit":6,"picture":"big","fields":["description","publishAt"],"ratio":"original"}})

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you could just inspect the element and overwrite the CSS like this:

Using color red for example:

```css
.medium-widget-article__description{
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="medium-widget">  
</div>
<script src="https://medium-widget.pixelpoint.io/widget.js">

</script>

<script>MediumWidget.Init({renderTo: '#medium-widget', params: {"resource":"https://medium.com/paradigm-fund/c%C3%B8smos-network-proposal-to-add-the-gravity-dex-onto-cosmos-hub-is-live-tendermint-invests-in-c68d8600e35b","postsPerLine":3,"limit":6,"picture":"big","fields":["description","publishAt"],"ratio":"original"}})

</script>
```

Quoted from [medium-widget.pixelpoint.io](https://medium-widget.pixelpoint.io/)

> Customize styles
> This widget does not use iframes, which allows you to
> override all of the existing styles used by it and make it look
> however you like. For example, you could customize the style of the
> article title by simply defining css properties for
> medium-widget-article__title class.